# correct way to pass service layer to threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

my service layer methods are transactional, when i use ExecutorService and submit task to threads, i cannot pass servicelayer as parameter to each threads, as i get error

```
Dec 14, 2009 10:40:18 AM com.companyx.applicationtest.applicationtestcompanyx.services.threadtestRunnable run
SEVERE: null
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and conf
iguration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext.currentSessio
n(SpringSessionContext.java:63)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactor
yImpl.java:542)
```

### *my service layer*

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
                  for (final Object item : CollectionsTest{ 
                      executor.submit(new threadtestRunnable((Long)item,collectionAfterfiltered,this));  //'this' is service layer
                  }
```

1. should i pass the service layer to each thread like this?
2. what is the proper way to do it, i need each thread to call method in service layer? (i'm using spring)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, however, does it make sense to run a transaction in multiple threads? typically a transaction is a predefined sequence of actions. if you do need parallel computing in a transaction, you can run them in worker threads, but have them report results back to the transaction thread where you commit them to database.

Comment: looking for someone to comment on this.. should transaction be in multiple threads?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, as said in the comments, transactions shouldn't be run in multiple threads. However, there are cases, where it is acceptable.

- you need to make some asynchronous communication with a web-service (without making the user wait for the result), and store the result when it comes
- you need read-only transactions in the multiple threads.

If you create your thread using `new`, it is not part of the spring context. Hence, when the method creating the thread finishes, your transaction interceptor will close the transaction (and session, eventually), and you will get the above exception.

(For more details - [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html), see "Lookup injection")

You need to create your threads within the spring context. And since you are probably creating them from a `singleton` bean, it is the rare case of creating `prototype` beans from a `singleton` bean. So in order to create a thread in the spring context, you can use:

```
 <bean id="mainBean"
    class="com.my.MyClass">
    <lookup-method name="createThread" bean="myThreadBean"/>
 </bean>
```

You should also map your `ThreadtestRunnable` class in the `applicationContext.xml` or annotate it as `@Component("myThreadBean")`.

Then define an `abstract` method on your main bean named `createThread` and returning your thread class. Annotate your run method with `@Transactional` (or define the appropriate aop rules), and try it. Perhaps you will need to set `propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW"` in your `@Transactional`. If anything is wrong, get back here.

Comment: by registering thread in xml. i no longer should call new threadtestRunnable((Long)item,collectionAfterfiltered,this) in ExecutionService right? and use applicationContext.getbean("thread") ?

Comment: no, you should call your createThread method and it will create the thread for you

Comment: why not just use @Configurable and minimize the required to change of code and only need to add annotation in ThreadtestRunnable

Comment: Either way should work. But adding @Configurable won't save much configuration ;) you will save one like for the lookup method replaced with one line for the load-time weaving

Comment: @cometta @Bozho hi, how to access the **items** in `run()` method?